# Running Wordpress & Meteor Same Server

Tags: wordpress, apache, meteor

We want to run Meteor on:

http://examplexyz.com/

And run Wordpress as a subfolder/virtual directory:

http://examplexyz.com/blog/

Is this possible with Meteor? To make the Meteor server pass requests for a particular directory to Apache?

Thanks,
Justin

Comment: Have you looked at using a proxy like nginx? It wouldn't be directly with meteor but you could add it as a transparent reverse proxy on top of your two apps

Comment: @Akshat Apache could do the same. My worry exists with how Meteor likes to use sockets to do realtime pushes/pulls as I'm unfamiliar how having Apache in between would mess with that.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to figure out how to get WordPress and MeteorJS to play nice, you should check out ButterCMS.

Here's a tutorial on how to build a CMS-powered blog with Meteor and ButterCMS:
https://buttercms.com/blog/meteor-cms-blog-tutorial